# How can I get the name of process displayed on monitor to terminate it?

Tags: windows, process, taskmanager

[image]

Hi, I am under pain for some broken Ads.

I want to terminate it but do not know which to terminate from task manager

I want to know what process is responsible to this annoying Ads

I am using Windows 10

Thanks in advance
Jaeyoon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cross-hair on the toolbar of [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)